# Select lightning:tree node from code

Tags: lightning

I have a lightning:tree component in my application. I can react to its `onselect` event but how can I mark a specific tree node a selected from the my component controller?

Comment: The way I see it, selected node will have a different class (like `active`) associated with it. You can add the class to selected node yourself in render-er.

Comment: I'm just a beginner with lighting components and never used renderer. Could you please share a link?

Comment: Please see this link for [renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) and the topic `Modifying the DOM` at bottom of the page